# pytesseract results different from tesseract command line results

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract, pytesser

I am trying to convert a scanned page to text using both pytesseract and tesseract command line on  Ubuntu. The results are remarkably different (pytesseract performs way better than tesseract command line) and I am unable to understand why. I looked at the default values for the parameters and tried altering some of the parameter values in tesseract command line (like psm ) but I am unable to get the same result as pytesseract. Due to lack of proper documentation  in pytesseract I am not able to figure out what default values for parameters are used.

Here is my pytesseract code
      `print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.tiff'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code of pytesseract, it seems the image is always converted into a .bmp file.
Working with a .bmp file and psm of 6 at the command line with Tesseract gives same result as pytesseract.
Also, tesseract can work with uncompressed bmp files only. Hence, if ImageMagick is used to convert .pdf to .bmp, the following will work

```
convert -density 300 -quality 100 mypdf.pdf BMP3:mypdf.bmp
tesseract mypdf.bmp -psm 6 mypdf txt
```

Comment: can you write a corresponding pyetesseract command with the density parameter?

Answer (score 0):

In tessaract v5 3.0+

Pytessaract does not convert images to BMP. You can verify this by commenting out `cleanup(f.name)` in the `save` context manager, which is found within the source code `/pytesseract/pytesseract.py`. The filename of the temp file will also need to retrieved (Pytessaract was saving files within temp files directory of the user, ie. "[path-to-user]\AppData\Local[file-name]". I found what Pytesseract is actually doing is in the `prepare` function.

Basically, taking the temp file and using that same file with the `tesseract` command directly will yeild the same results